# Call a method to redirect inside react native Async function, is it possible?

Tags: firebase, react-native, promise, firebase-authentication

Im making a react native application and using firebase to authenticate my user credentials as shown here: (edited to include more code).

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, Button, TextInput, Alert } from 'react-native';
import { firebaseRef } from '../config/firebase';

 class register extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {firstName: '', lastName:'', email: '', password: '', confirmPassword: '', success: true};
    this.register = this.register.bind(this); //grants access to the state objects
}

 redirect(){
    this.props.navigation.navigate('home');
 }

register(){
  firebaseRef.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password).then(function(user) {
  Alert.alert('Congratulations', 'You have successfully registered your email address');
}, 
  function(error) {
    Alert.alert('Registration Failed', 'failure');
    console.log(error.code);
    console.log(error.message);
    this.redirect();
  });
}

 failedRegistration(){
  Alert.alert('Registration Failed', 'failure');
  this.setState({success: false});
 }

 successfulRegistration(){
  Alert.alert('Well Done', 'You have successfully registered.');
 }

 render() {
    return (
      <View style={{backgroundColor:'cyan', flex:1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
      <TextInput
            style={{backgroundColor:'orange', width: 200}}
            returnKeyType='next'
            placeholder='first name'
            onChangeText={(input) => this.setState({firstName: input})}
            value={this.props.input}
            />
      <TextInput
          style={{backgroundColor:'orange', width: 200}}
          returnKeyType='next'
          placeholder='last name'
          onChangeText={(input) => this.setState({lastName: input})}
          value={this.props.input}
          />
      <TextInput
          style={{backgroundColor:'orange', width: 200}}
          returnKeyType='next'
          placeholder='email'
          onChangeText={(input) => this.setState({email: input})}
          value={this.props.input}
          />
      <TextInput
            style={{backgroundColor:'orange', width: 200}}
            returnKeyType='next'
            placeholder='password'
            onChangeText={(input) => this.setState({password: input})}
            value={this.props.input}
            />
      <TextInput
          style={{backgroundColor:'orange', width: 200}}
          returnKeyType='next'
          placeholder='password'
          onChangeText={(input) => this.setState({confirmPassword: input})}
          value={this.props.input}
          />
          <Text>{this.state.firstName}</Text>
          <Text>{this.state.lastName}</Text>
          <Text>{this.state.email}</Text>
          <Text>{this.state.password}</Text>
          <Text>{this.state.confirmPassword}</Text>
        <Button title={'REGISTER'} onPress={() => this.register()}></Button>
      </View>
    )
  }
```

}

export default register;
If I call a method like this.redirect() it returns the error 'this.redirect is not a function'.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please include more code including where you are calling this.redirect(). It is likely that you are not binding the call, however cannot tell for sure without looking at more code

Comment: @coderhacker updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to get around this : Store this in another variable and use that to call the function.

```
register(){
  var that = this;
  firebaseRef.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password).then(function(user) {
  Alert.alert('Congratulations', 'You have successfully registered your email address');
}, 
  function(error) {
    Alert.alert('Registration Failed', 'failure');
    console.log(error.code);
    console.log(error.message);
    that.redirect();
  });
}
```

Also you can bind the function in following way

```
<Button title={'REGISTER'} onPress={this.register.bind(this)}></Button>
```

Comment: brilliant solution! I used "var that = this;" but why would binding my onpress be a good idea? what does it do?

Comment: Just a tip: When ever you have a callback, always bind with this. This ensures that the 'this' used in the function is one that points to the component. (Its another one way of achieving what you did in constructor). I have seen people mostly do it in callbacks.